# Extract specific lines (indices given) from a file (strings)

Tags: awk

I have two files: lines.txt and idx.txt

```
lines.txt:
aaa ggg sss
ww ee ttt
qq ee gg ccc
vvv bb b www ee
ppp dff f gg qq
pp qq ee rr tt
ww qq ee rrr

idx.txt
2
4
5
```

I would like to use "idx.txt" to extract those specific lines from "lines.txt" file. The files are pretty big (tens of MB). Currently I am using the following line but it is slow:

```
awk 'NR=FNR{arr[FNR]=$0; next} {for(i in arr) if(i==$1) print arr[i]}' lines.txt idx.txt
```

I am generating the "idx.txt" files using a script, hence the extraction of the lines should be fast.

Has somebody more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} FNR in a' idx.txt lines.txt
```

Comment: Heh you wrote that with your eyes closed didn't you?

Comment: Blazingly fast compared to my scraped from www version! Thanks!

Comment: If want to extract inverse selection:
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} FNR in a == 0' idx.txt lines.txt

Comment: @xeon or simpler `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !(FNR in a)' idx.txt lines.txt`